# Batch file to prompt UAC like Run as administrator

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

How can I get a batch file to prompt for UAC on Windows Vista to Windows 8 to run with Administrator rights - that is - other than right clicking on the batch file and hitting "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894967/how-to-request-administrator-access-inside-a-batch-file

Answer (score 1):

By using 3rd party tool [elevate.exe](http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate) like this:

```
elevate example.bat
```